# Updating menus through inflation

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

In my application, I manage the options menu to reflect the state my application is in. Three menus are possible.

In the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function, I inflate the basic entries from an XML file.

In the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` function, I clear the menu and then inflate the XML file which corresponds to the current state of my application.

And this leads to unexpected results!!!

When I change the menu from state 1 to state 2 and then revert to state 1, the "more" entry is visually replaced by one of the entries of my menu. But it's function is correct : if I click on it, the overflow menu appears!

And then, if I change for state 3, no menu appears when I try to open it. And if I debug the code, I see the menu is correctly filled with the result of the inflation (the size of the menu changes accordingly).

I can add that the code works perfectly with Android 2.3.3. The problem only occurs when I execute it on Android 4 (not tested with Android 3).

Any idea?

As requested, I have simplified my code to let you see the problem.
The code of the application is below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private boolean m2=false,m3=false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflateur;

    inflateur = getMenuInflater();
    inflateur.inflate(R.menu.menu_1,menu);
    return (true);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflateur;

    inflateur = getMenuInflater();
    menu.clear();

    if (m2){
        inflateur.inflate(R.menu.menu_2,menu);
    } else {
        if(m3) {
            inflateur.inflate(R.menu.menu_3, menu);
        } else {
            inflateur.inflate(R.menu.menu_1, menu);
        }
    }

    return (true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem entréeMenu) {
    switch (entréeMenu.getItemId()) {
        case R.menu.m1_4: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_5: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_7: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_8: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_10: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_12: {
            return (true);
        }

        case R.menu.m1_13: {
            return (true);
        }

        case R.menu.m1_1: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_11: {
            // change for menu_2
            m2=true;
            m3=false;
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m3_1: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m3_2: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m2_1: {
            // revert to menu_1
            m2=false;
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m2_2: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_2: {
            // change for menu_3
            m2=false;
            m3=true;
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_3: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m3_3: {
            // revert to menu_1
            m3=false;
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m2_5: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m2_3: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m2_4: {
            return true;
        }

        case R.menu.m1_6: {
            return (true);
        }

        case R.menu.Options: {
            return (true);
        }

        case R.menu.m1_14:{
            return(true);
        }

        default: {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(entréeMenu);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Only four menu entries are active : 1.11 changes from menu_1 to menu_2, 2.1 reverts to menu_1; 1.2 changes from menu_1 to menu_3 and 3.3 reverts to menu_1.

The problems encountered so far :
1) click on 1.11 to change for menu_2. Open the menu : only 5 menu items are displayed. Close the menu and re-open it : the 6 menu items are now correctly displayed.
2) click on 2.1 to return to menu 1. In the sixth position, you can see "2.6" instead of "more". If you click on "2.6", the behaviour corresponds to a click on "more".

And now, the XML files for the menus :
menu_1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_1"
      android:title="1.1">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_2"
      android:title="1.2">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_3"
      android:title="1.3">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_4"
      android:title="1.4">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_5"
      android:title="1.5"
      android:checkable="true">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_6"
      android:title="1.6"
      android:checkable="true">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_7"
      android:title="1.7"
      android:checkable="true">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_8"
      android:title="1.8"
      android:checkable="true">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_9"
      android:title="1.9"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:visible="false"
      android:checkable="true">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_10"
      android:title="1.10">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_11"
      android:title="1.11">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_12"
      android:title="1.12">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_13"
      android:title="1.13">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_14"
    android:title="1.14">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/Options"
    android:title="1.15">
</item>
```

menu_2 :

```
 <item android:id="@+menu/m2_2"
      android:title="2.2">
 </item>

 <item android:id="@+menu/m2_3"
      android:title="2.3">
 </item>

 <item android:id="@+menu/m2_4"
      android:title="2.4">
 </item>

 <item android:id="@+menu/m2_5"
      android:title="2.5">
 </item>

<item android:id="@+menu/Options"
    android:title="2.6">
</item>
</menu>
```

and menu_3 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+menu/m3_1"
      android:title="3.1">
 </item>

 <item android:id="@+menu/m3_2"
      android:title="3.2">
 </item>

 <item android:id="@+menu/m3_3"
      android:title="3.3">
 </item>

<item android:id="@+menu/m1_4"
      android:title="3.4">
</item>

<item android:id="@+menu/Options"
    android:title="3.5">
</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: how about posting some code? no one has any idea what your "more" entryx might be...

Comment: The "more" entry isn't mine. It is the entry placed in sixth position by the system when the menu contains more than six items.